# Cloud SQL / MySQL server fails after deploying to Google Cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a Google App Engine application that operates perfectly when run locally using `localhost:8080`, but after I deploy to the cloud using `gcloud app deploy`, I receive the following error:

```
Warning: PDO::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away in /base/data/home/apps/s~fileabcd/20190320t221240.123456737151234567/gac_abcd.php on line 7

Warning: PDO::__construct(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=-1 in /base/data/home/apps/s~fileabcd/20190320t221240.123456737151234567/gac_abcd.php on line 7
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the reason why my Google App Engine (GAE) application functioned properly on localhost, but threw a `MySQL server has gone away` error after being deployed to [PROJECT-ID].appspot.com.

The reason is because my application was connecting to a Cloud SQL instance in a different project, and in order to do this you must grant the default appengine service account ([PROJECT-ID]@appspot.gserviceaccount.com) one of the following IAM roles:

- Cloud SQL Client
- Cloud SQL Editor
- Cloud SQL Admin

After I added the App Engine default service account as a `Cloud SQL Client` Role in the project containing the Cloud SQL instance, everything worked perfectly.

From the [Cloud SQL documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine).

Comment: my sql and app engine are on same project, although I still get "forbidden" message suggesting I should add SQL client/admin to principal IAM, and I did and still get errors